# How to get schema information from a RESTful uri?

Tags: restful-url, restful-architecture

Is there a way to get schema information from a RESTful web service?  For example, a soap service has WSDL that we can look at and create any proxy classes.  I was wondering if there is a way to get that information from a restful web service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These helped:

[Creating a Help Page for a Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/creating-a-help-page-for-a-web-api)

[Similar Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10695095/asp-net-web-api-automatically-generate-api-documentation)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to get schema information from a RESTful web service?

In general, no. REST doesn't include metadata about its payload - that's not the purpose of this architectural style.

Such metadata shouldn't be needed if the web service is truly REST conformant.

You will need to look at the payloads and documentation.

Comment: How about this: [Use IAPIExplorer To List Your ASP.NET Web APIs](http://www.infoq.com/news/2012/05/iapiexplorer).

Comment: @KO. - What about it? Looks like it fits your needs, though standard, it ain't.